# Datepicker shown wrong position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

i try to shown `datepicker` in modal, but the result is like this :

[image]

`datepicker` shown in wrong place, but when i try the code in `jsfiddle` is work fine

this is my link : http://jsfiddle.net/alverhothasi/D7bBg/

i use SUPERHERO from bootswatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a css conflict, since you've also tagged bootstrap. Jquery UI is known to have problems with bootstrap. There is a [Jquery UI theme suitable for bootstrap](https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/), you can try it.

For a quick fix, try adding following css to `idTourDateDetails`:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100000;
```

This might give the datepicker the correct z-index.